# How to change NSIS installer background color based on system color

Tags: installation, accessibility, nsis

It seems that NSIS has hardcoded the background color to be white.

Whenever high contrast is turned on, the background remains white while the text is reverted to white (to comply with high contrast).

Is there a way to determine the current system colors and change the background accordingly?

Comment: Windows version?

Comment: Are you talking about the white parts in the Modern UI? Or the log/list on the InstFiles page?

Comment: Testing it against Windows 10 and current version of NSIS. Talking about the first and last page of the installer. The headers take those colors as well. @Anders

Comment: I see the problem and I'll try to figure out what the best solution is. It might require some hacks until I can get it fixed for the next release.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are not using a wizard/header image that depends on the background being white you can simply do

```
!define MUI_BGCOLOR "SYSCLR:Window"
!include MUI2.nsh
...
```

in recent versions of NSIS v3.

If you want to force black on white then you must manually change the Modern UI .nsh files. Look for lines that look like `SetCtlColors $SomeNameHere "" "${MUI_BGCOLOR}"` and change them to `SetCtlColors $SomeNameHere "000000" "FFFFFF"`.

Comment: Thanks for your help! This actually fixed the issue. It does make the default option look a little outdated but it's a fair price for an accessible option.

Comment: @rezpawn I will add a text color setting in the next version.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to determine if the current setting is in high contrast so that we can change the setting accordingly? It really just has to match normal Windows setting.

Comment: You can use `${If} ${IsHighContrastModeActive}` if you copy the code from the bottom of https://sourceforge.net/p/nsis/code/7013/tree//NSIS/trunk/Include/Util.nsh

Answer (score 0):

To expand a bit on [Ander's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52238195/3196753)... the above code will also fix the Welcome text in high-contrast mode.  I'd even make the argument that for accessibility reasons should be default on all installers.

```
!define MUI_BGCOLOR "SYSCLR:Window"
!define MUI_TEXTCOLOR "SYSCLR:WindowText"
!include MUI2.nsh
...
```